# Error in wc command to read number of lines in file

Tags: linux, text-processing, wc

I have been using `wc -l` to check for the number of lines exist in my files. It worked fine always but not this time.

I have 120 big files that are supposed to have at least two lines in each of them. I have just done some text editing work on those files to remove and add new lines. I was trying to check the final number of line by using `wc -l *` as usual. The output showed that most of the files had only one line.

I opened up one of the file (which showed from the result of the command that it had only one line) with `vim` and I can see that it had exactly 2 lines. Exit `vim` and check again using `wc -l`, the number of line for that file then appeared as 2.

Does anyone have any idea with what happened over here? And how can I solve this problem instead of opening all 120 files with `vim`?

PS: The final line of my files weren't empty.

Comment: I don't see from your question what the error is exactly.

Comment: @schaiba Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The `wc -l` command doesn't show precise line number for my files here. But it was corrected only after I tried editing the file using `vim`

Comment: Does the last line contain any characters?

Comment: @RakibFiha Yes. The new lines I meant here are not empty.

Comment: Does Vim show `[noeol]` at the bottom when you first open one of these files with the editor?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes there is.

Comment: @web So, the last line would then not be counted by `wc -l` since `wc -l` counts newlines.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see, but is it still possible to make it visible for `wc`?

Comment: @web, you need to either alter your idea of what the `wc` program does (it doesn't count "lines" it counts newline characters) or you need to fix your files so they end with newline characters. I give a couple of ways of how to do that in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common gnu implementation of `wc` says

> ‘wc’ counts the number of bytes, characters, whitespace-separated words,
>   and newlines in each given FILE, or standard input if none are given or                                         for a FILE of ‘-’.

so if there is no final newline character in the file the "lines" part of the `wc` output will be one less than expected. For example the following will output 1

```
printf 'hello\nworld' | wc -l
```

The OP has confirmed in comments that vim is reporting the lack of the final newline.
A simple fix if all the files are known to have this problem is

```
 for f in *
 do
     echo >> "$f"
 done
```

to append a newline to each file.

A way to add a newline conditionally to the end of all the files if they are missing one is to use sed.

```
sed -s -i '$s/$/\n/;P;d' *
```

uses some gnu extensions, `-s` to treat each file separately, `-i` to do an in place edit, and allowing `\n` to represent a newline. The sed program itself says on the last line of each file append a newline, and for each line print up to the first newline and move onto the next line.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might cause some confusion on the term "newlines" here. The new lines that I have added in or deleted contained character. Btw, regarding the sayings that "It is likely that something in this work removed the final newline.", I actually check it with vim after the edit and the total number of line was not precisely shown in `wc` output.

Comment: If you take a file that you have not fixed, and run `hexdump -C` on it, is the final character shown as 0a in the hex part of the display?

Comment: @web Removed comment the the editing might have removed the final newline.

Comment: not really sure what do you mean by final character in the hex part. Would you mind to further explain about it?

Comment: `printf 'hi\nthere' | hexdump -C` outputs `00000000  68 69 0a 74 68 65 72 65                           |hi.there|`. the hex part ends `65 72 65` and so doesn't end with `0a`

Comment: I see...the hex part doesn't end with 0a then.

Comment: @web, `od -c ` is also usefull for this kind of analisys.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly  an answer, but sharing a micro personal tool I use often to
normalize text files (txtnorm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -spi
our($s);
s/\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g;                 ## normalize \n
s/^(\xFF\xFE|\xFE\xFF|\xEF\xBB\xBF)//;  ## remove BOM !
s/(?<=.)\z/\n/;                         ## ensure newline at eof

if($s){ s/\xC2\xA0/ /g }                ## -s non breaking spaces-> " "
```

`txtnorm  *.txt` normalizes end-of-lines, ensures newlines at eof, removes BOMs and (with -s) may normalize non-breaking spaces.

Be sure to use it JUST on text files.